# how to improve ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, boxplot

I have a boxplot output in R using ggplot2. [box plot i got using the below code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njmJI.jpg)

[image]

I want to label each box plot as labelled in the sample plot. [sample plot i want to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vqqdw.jpg)

[image]

I have calculated p-value that is 0.06 for first egg1. i would like to paste this text on the plot as shown in the sample plot. how i can do that?

```
ggplot(testdata) +
geom_boxplot(aes(x=variable, y=value, color= as.factor (classification)))
```

Comment: Check out these packages https://github.com/kassambara/ggpubr & https://github.com/IndrajeetPatil/ggstatsplot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `annotate` to add text on your boxplot:

```
ggplot(testdata) +
geom_boxplot(aes(x=variable, y=value, color= as.factor (classification))) +
annotate(geom="text", x=1, y=6, label="p = 0.06")
```

Comment: Dear @dc37, thanks for the suggestion it works and displays a label p=0.06 above egg1 plots. I have 3 groups of box plots, one label has been correctly placed, would you please explain how to put labels on remaining two groups?

Comment: Hi Usman, just re-use `annotate` by changing x location and label. For example, for the second group, you can do `+ annotate(geom="text", x= 5, y = 6, label = "p = 0.10")`, adapt it based on your current p value you want to display.

Comment: Hi @dc37, thanks it works. another question, how to add simple legends for this plot?

Comment: What do you mean by simple legends ? You're already have legends on the right side of your plot .

Comment: i wanted to rename the legend title. I did it. Thank you.